# can there be a situation in which the flock command ends up in deadlock?

Tags: bash, shell, locking, deadlock, flock

```
set -e

pidfile=/data/demo3

# lock it
exec 200<>$pidfile
flock -n 200 || exit 1

# my code 
echo "hello"
sleep 20
echo "bi"
```

I have a text file and several process can access this text file at the same time. So I am using flock command to insure the concurrency issue. So a process locks a file at time = T1  and other process want to lock the same file at the same time = T1 So won't this cause a problem that which process will lock the file first or will this situation end up in deadlock?
or am i missing something?

If I am using this code and i am locking this demo3 file and at the same time another process want to lock this file so won't this cause an issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you include some existing code to illustrate your concern?

Comment: I have added it. Can you check it now it would be a big help. I am trying to work on a project here and my deadline is near.

Comment: What is this process, and the other processes, doing to/with the `/data/demo3` file?  Are they also bash scripts, or are they other programs?  Are the other scripts/programs using `flock` consistently?

Comment: they are bash scripts and they have flock inside it to lock on this demo3.json file. Suppose this same script is run by 2 terminals at the same time so can this be a issue?

Answer (score 0):

No there should be no deadlock or contention.

Once a process running this script gets past `flock`, only that process' `# my code` section will run until the process terminates.  Other instances (processes) of the script will fail with `exit 1` at `flock`.